# How to skip the first occurrence of a pattern and replace rest of the string from second occurrence

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I would like to skip the first occurrence of a pattern (`_` in this example) and then substitute rest of the string including the pattern with tab. For example:

```
T004_7_entry_00007_conf_01
```

Desired output:

```
T004_7
```

I have tried the following in sed:

```
sed 's/_.*\t/\t/'
```

Comment: `s/(\_)([^\_]*)\_(.*?)$/$1$2/g;`

Answer (score 3):

For given sample, there are various ways to solve it

```
$ echo 'T004_7_entry_00007_conf_01' | sed 's/\(_[^_]*\).*/\1\t/'
T004_7
```

- `\(_[^_]*\)` is a capture group to save the first occurrence

  - `\(` and `\)` are meta-characters to specify a capture group, `\` won't be needed if ERE is used
  - `[^_]*` means zero or more non `_` characters, so this solution is suited for single character delimiter only
- `\1` is a back-reference to the first capture group
- See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions) for more details on regular expressions

Other ways:

```
$ echo 'T004_7_entry_00007_conf_01' | perl -pe 's/_[^_]*\K.*/\t/'
T004_7  

$ echo 'T004_7_entry_00007_conf_01' | awk -F_ '{print $1 FS $2 "\t" }'
T004_7
```

Field based solution is better suited if delimiter is not single character

```
$ echo 'foo_:_baz_:_123_:_456' | awk -F_:_ '{print $1 FS $2 "\t" }'
foo_:_baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/\([^_]*\)\(_[^_]*\)\(.*\)/\1\2\t/'  Input_file
```

kindly use `i` or `i.bak`(to take backup of previous Input_file) in case you want to save output into Input_file itself.

With `awk`:

```
awk 'match($0,/^[[:alnum:]]+_[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)\t}' Input_file
```

Comment: Great, again DOWN VOTER without any comments :( :(

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but... constructive feedback... The question specifically asked that we have a `\t` as a replacement for the second `_` and beyond.  Your answers doesn't replace with `\t`. In the sed answer, you could reduce to one back-reference, but that would essentially dupe Sundeep's.  The comment after your first answer is not clear -- and unnecessary.  In the awk answer, the match regex has additional conditions/assumptions beyond the `_` requirement -- suggest you use `[^_]*` instead of the more narrowly defined character classes.  Hope this feedback is taken positively. :)

Comment: @MichaelBack, thank you for letting me know completely missed it my bad, added `\t` it now, my concern was no comment so I asked. Thanks, let me know if I missed something here too.

Answer (score 0):

Very carefully written **sed** back-reference based answer -- close to @*Sundeep*'s, but that makes sure that you actually have a second occurrence of `_`:

```
sed 's/\(_[^_]*\)_.*/\1\t/'
```

With **awk** we could offer more creative solutions.  Here is a straightforward **awk** implementation using regex:

```
awk 'match($0, /[^_]*_[^_]*_/) { $0 = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH - 1) "\t" } 1'
```

Here is an example that completely eschew's regex pattern matching to do what you want by taking advantage of (abusing) the field separator feature:

```
awk -F_ 'NF > 2 { $0 = $1 FS $2 "\t" } 1'
```

Note that all of the above carefully follow your example to emulate the kind of default behavior you would get with sed -- that being to pass through and print all lines, including non-matching ones.  All carefully replace the second occurrence of `_` plus text that follows with `\t` -- all lines that do not have more than one `_` are passed through as unedited.

If we want to limit the output to print only matching lines, we can replace the `$0 =` in both examples with `print` and delete the trailing `1`.